# How to solve this error in Visual studio: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Tags: c#, string, implicit-conversion

I tried to receive the trap message from a listener code and store it in a string and append that to the messageAndAlerts messages, so that it would display that trap message along with the other alert messages. But error is thrown in the line:

```
List<string> result = TrapMessages;
```

For Trapmessage saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

```
string TrapMessages;
try
{
    Thread thr = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SnmpTrapRecv recv = new SnmpTrapRecv();
        TrapMessages = recv.Listener();
        List<string> result = TrapMessages;
        messagesAndAlerts.AddRange(result);
    }
);
    //  thr.IsBackground = true;
    thr.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.DebugFormat("snmptrap execption:{0}", ex.Message);
}

return messagesAndAlerts;
```

Comment: `List<string> result = new List<string>(); result.Add(TrapMessages);`

Comment: Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @RobertHarveyYou should add it as answer. This answers his question.

Comment: thank you.... this answers my question...